# How to calculate determinant of matrices without loop?

Tags: matlab, loops, matrix

I am new to Matlab and this might seem very easy.

I have 2 matrices:

```matlab
a = [1 1 1; 2 2 2 ; 3 3 3 ; 4 4 4 ; 5 5 5];
b = [4 4 4; 3 2 4 ; 1 5 7 ; 4 3 8 ; 2 4 7];
```

I wanted to calculate the determinant of each row of the two matrices added by a row of ones (a 3*3 matrix), and put all the determinants in another array. For example, first determinant (`d(1)`) would be from this matrix:

```
1 1 1
4 4 4
1 1 1
```

and the second one (`d(2)`) would be from this matrix:

```
2 2 2
3 2 4
1 1 1
```

and so on...

When I try this:

```matlab
m = size(a,1);
ons = ones(m,3);
d = det([a(:,:) ; b(:,:) ; ons(:,:)]);
```

I get this error:

> Error using det
>
> Matrix must be square.

How can I calculate all the determinants at once without using loop?

Comment: What do you mean by "the determinant of each row"? The determinant is only defined for square matrices, and built-ins will only compute it one matrix at a time.

Comment: do you understand the error you got ?

Comment: The determinant of `A`, a transformation matrix `Rm -> Rm`, calculate the ratio between the surface (in 2D or hypersurface in mD) obtained if we apply those transformation matrix to some surface (in 2D or hypersurface in mD) and the original surface. So it  does not make any sens to compute the determinant of a non square matrix because we would compute, for example, the ratio between a volume and a surface and obtain infinity as a result.

Comment: OK, so I agree you have matrices. As far as I can tell built-in `det` will only compute one determinant at a time. However, if your matrices are always 3x3, you can hand-code the determinant (it has 6 terms), which you can do in a vectorized way, if you prefer.

Comment: @AndrasDeak Yes they are always 3x3. I will try to do it in a vectorized way using the six terms. For the first term for example, it should be: `a(:,1) * b(:,2) * 1`.

Comment: I think so, yes. But don't forget to double-check your result with a loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on @Andras's suggestion, I tried the determinant according to [wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant):

[image: fgdg]

Based on @beaker's suggestion, this works:

```matlab
d = (a(:, 1) .* b(:, 2) - a(:, 2) .* b(:, 1)) - (a(:, 1) .* b(:, 3) - a(:, 3) .* b(:, 1)) + (a(:, 2) .* b(:, 3) - a(:, 3) .* b(:, 2))
```

These are slower alternatives:

```matlab
d = arrayfun(@(x)det([a(x,:);b(x,:);ones(1,3)]),1:length(a));
```

```matlab
d = bsxfun(@times, a(:,1), b(:,2))+ bsxfun(@times, a(:,2), b(:,3)) +...
    bsxfun(@times, a(:,3), b(:,1))- bsxfun(@times, a(:,3), b(:,2)) -...
    bsxfun(@times, a(:,2), b(:,1))- bsxfun(@times, a(:,1), b(:,3));
```

Comment: `arrayfun` is just a loop hidden in a function call. It would be interesting to see timings comparing `arrayfun`, a `for` loop, and the vectorized calculation of the individual terms.

Comment: @beaker Do you have any idea for the **vectorized** calculation?

Comment: I was referring to the method you discussed with @AndrasDeak in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58294880/how-to-calculate-determinant-of-matrices-without-loop/58307603?noredirect=1#comment102971352_58294880).

Comment: @beaker I tried that and added in the answer, but did not work. every element of `d` became `0`.

Comment: That's not what we discussed. I don't think you need `bsxfun`. What you might need is simply `.*` (elementwise multiplication) rather than `*` (matrix multiplication). Perhaps the actual indices are off (in the wrong order), I didn't check that thoroughly.

Comment: One difficulty is that the example matrices you've chosen all have determinants of 0. But all you should need is `d = (a(:, 1) .* b(:, 2) - a(:, 2) .* b(:, 1)) - (a(:, 1) .* b(:, 3) - a(:, 3) .* b(:, 1)) + (a(:, 2) .* b(:, 3) - a(:, 3) .* b(:, 2))`